# Wicket AuthorizeInstantiation

Tags: wicket, role-base-authorization

In `Wicket`, I have to use `@AuthorizeInstantiation` to restrict access based on roles. otherwise access is allowed to all.

I want reverse behavior: Restrict all the pages by default (allow only if `@AuthorizeInstantiation` is specified)

How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you use RolesAuthorizationStrategy that delegates to `AnnotationsRoleAuthorizationStrategy`. Its [code](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/dfa32cd151fec1e85ed65a83a363ef33144a652e/wicket-auth-roles/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/authroles/authorization/strategies/role/annotations/AnnotationsRoleAuthorizationStrategy.java#L55) says:

```
@Override
public <T extends IRequestableComponent> boolean isInstantiationAuthorized(
    final Class<T> componentClass)
{
    // We are authorized unless we are found not to be
    boolean authorized = true;
    ...
```

At the moment I see no other way than to create a custom `IAuthorizationStrategy` that starts with `authorized = false` and then does the same.

You can create a ticket at Wicket JIRA to make this initial value a member field that is initialized from a constructor parameter. This way you won't need to copy code and it will be as easy as `new AnnotationsRoleAuthorizationStrategy(false)`

Comment: Yes, but please don't use a `boolean`, but rather an `enum` which directly shows what is going on. For example `DefaultAuthoriziation.ALLOW`, `DefaultAuthoriziation.DENY`. That makes code a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is the specify the `@AuthorizeInstantiation` on package level.

`package-info.java`:

```
@AuthorizeInstantiation("ADMIN")
package your_domain.your_app.your_package;

import org.apache.wicket.authroles.authorization.strategies.role.annotations.AuthorizeInstantiation;
```

This doesn't apply to sub-packages though.